# submit form to form different url

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm having problem in this case, how to submit form to submit other form in different url....

example:

form1.php:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     <input type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="submit">
</form>
```

form2.html:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     <input type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="submit">
</form>
```

how can I submit form1 and form2 at the same time??

Comment: why are you using two forms ? use name like name[ ] that gives you array of input field and then submit.

Comment: @Sagar, because form2 in machine does not support php file. any example how i can submit?

Comment: you can use laravel view like blade files where you can define form and then submit.  Are you trying to submit via Ajax call ?

Comment: Both forms are on same page or in different pages?

Comment: @Sagar, yes i using laravel, you have examle to submit form?

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap, different page and differrnt url... because second form using machine does not support php file

Comment: @muzamilindra general form submit is too easy . If form submit in single page can help, I can help you

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in laravel, so below is the implementation in JS.

Move form2.html in form1.php using an  and make it invisible as shown below :

```
<iframe src="form2.html" style="display:none" name="form2"></iframe>
```

Then in form1.php, make following changes :

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <input type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()">
</form>
```

Here we are removing default submit action of form, instead we are calling submitForm() function when submit button is hit.

```
function submitForm(){
//first we will submit form2.html 
window.frames["form2"].document.forms[0].submit();
document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using single form it's too easy. Use array input of name like:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('create/name')}}" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Name One</label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Name Two</label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now you can define route in web.php

```
Route::post('create/name','NameController@postName');
```

And finally write some logic to create name in NameController as:

```
public function postName(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->name as $name){
         //Write logic to create Name.
    }
}
```

Using single blade page, you can submit Name like this without Ajax call. Hope this might help you.

Comment: form2 different machine, using html file not using laravel. only form1 using laravel

Comment: If you want to submit from different machine at same time then, it will be difficult to maintain that

Comment: And I still don't understand about term 'Another Machine'